# Changing the size of the text in the axis labels of an Ecdf plot

Tags: r, ecdf, hmisc

I've constructed an `Ecdf` plot from the `Hmisc` package with the following call:

```
require(Hmisc)
Ecdf(latency_targ1, group = CONDITION, lty = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
        lwd = 4, label.curves = list(method = 'arrow', 
        keys = "lines", lwd = 2), xlim = c(0,500), 
        subtitles = FALSE, xlab = "Latency", 
        ylab = "Proportion latency <= x")
```

I have been unable to find how to change the size of the axis labels of the plot and the default size is rather small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ecdf(latency_targ1, group = CONDITION, lty = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
    lwd = 4, label.curves = list(method = 'arrow', 
    keys = "lines", lwd = 2), xlim = c(0,500), 
    subtitles = FALSE, xlab = "Latency", 
    ylab = "Proportion latency <= x", 
    cex.lab=1.5, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
axis(2, cex.axis=1.5)
axis(1, cex.axis=1.5)
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked well. Is it the case that cex.lab gets passed to par? In general for Ecdf calls can par settings be set like this, directly in the Ecdf call?